# ggplot2 - error plotting subset of data frame after changing column to date class

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe `df` and am trying to make some nice `facet_grid` plots with the Date, User, Activity and Dose data.

```
        Date.Issued       Date User         Activity       Dose
1  28/04/2021 13:19 28/04/2021    A Technologist PET  3.3098681
2  28/04/2021 08:59 28/04/2021    G Technologist PET  9.7787209
3  28/04/2021 08:58 28/04/2021    M Technologist PET  6.4040399
4  28/04/2021 08:58 28/04/2021    L Technologist PET  4.8086505
5  28/04/2021 08:58 28/04/2021    H Technologist PET  0.0000000
6  28/04/2021 08:44 28/04/2021    G  Technologist NM  4.6328144
7  28/04/2021 08:43 28/04/2021    K  Technologist NM 12.4208622
8  28/04/2021 08:43 28/04/2021    R  Technologist NM  2.8641932
9  28/04/2021 08:42 28/04/2021    A  Technologist NM  8.4690704
10 28/04/2021 08:31 28/04/2021    P Technologist PET  4.2168984
11 28/04/2021 08:23 28/04/2021    C Technologist PET 28.1236839
12 28/04/2021 08:23 28/04/2021    S Technologist PET 10.3116798
13 28/04/2021 08:11 28/04/2021    H Technologist PET 13.7067385
14 27/04/2021 09:17 27/04/2021    C Technologist PET  8.9209318
15 27/04/2021 09:12 27/04/2021    G  Technologist NM  3.8493500
16 27/04/2021 09:11 27/04/2021    K  Technologist NM  2.3508735
17 27/04/2021 09:11 27/04/2021    A  Technologist NM  1.8516742
18 27/04/2021 09:10 27/04/2021    R  Technologist NM  3.9221160
19 27/04/2021 09:07 27/04/2021    G Technologist PET 15.1844616
20 27/04/2021 08:51 27/04/2021    L Technologist PET 10.0322027
21 27/04/2021 08:16 27/04/2021    S Technologist PET  8.2122355
22 27/04/2021 08:16 27/04/2021    H Technologist PET  6.6248207
23 27/04/2021 08:16 27/04/2021    P Technologist PET  3.8532472
24 26/04/2021 13:00 26/04/2021    A Technologist PET  2.5060282
25 26/04/2021 09:30 26/04/2021    P Technologist PET  9.5917282
26 26/04/2021 09:17 26/04/2021    G Technologist PET 14.0576487
27 26/04/2021 08:53 26/04/2021    M Technologist PET  4.3697691
28 26/04/2021 08:52 26/04/2021    C Technologist PET  7.1182218
29 26/04/2021 08:27 26/04/2021    A  Technologist NM  2.1964765
30 26/04/2021 08:26 26/04/2021    R  Technologist NM  1.4743344
31 26/04/2021 08:25 26/04/2021    L  Technologist NM  3.4398077
32 26/04/2021 08:25 26/04/2021    K  Technologist NM  0.9920691
33 26/04/2021 08:24 26/04/2021    G  Technologist NM  1.4903276
34 26/04/2021 08:24 26/04/2021    C  Technologist NM  0.0000000
35 26/04/2021 08:20 26/04/2021    S Technologist PET  8.9420223
36 26/04/2021 08:01 26/04/2021    H Technologist PET  6.6264949
```

My `Date` column is not in date format in R, so I convert the class using `as.Date`

```
    >Attach(df)
    >Date
    >[1] "28/04/2021" "28/04/2021" "28/04/2021" "28/04/2021" "28/04/2021" "28/04/2021" "28/04/2021" "28/04/2021" "28/04/2021" "28/04/2021" "28/04/2021" "28/04/2021" "28/04/2021" "27/04/2021" "27/04/2021" "27/04/2021" "27/04/2021"
    [18] "27/04/2021" "27/04/2021" "27/04/2021" "27/04/2021" "27/04/2021" "27/04/2021" "26/04/2021" "26/04/2021" "26/04/2021" "26/04/2021" "26/04/2021" "26/04/2021" "26/04/2021" "26/04/2021" "26/04/2021" "26/04/2021" "26/04/2021"
    [35] "26/04/2021" "26/04/2021"
    >class(Date)
    [1] "character"
    >DateX <- as.Date(Date, "%d/%m/%Y")
    >DateX
    [1] "2021-04-28" "2021-04-28" "2021-04-28" "2021-04-28" "2021-04-28" "2021-04-28" "2021-04-28" "2021-04-28" "2021-04-28" "2021-04-28" "2021-04-28" "2021-04-28" "2021-04-28" "2021-04-27" "2021-04-27" "2021-04-27" "2021-04-27"
    [18] "2021-04-27" "2021-04-27" "2021-04-27" "2021-04-27" "2021-04-27" "2021-04-27" "2021-04-26" "2021-04-26" "2021-04-26" "2021-04-26" "2021-04-26" "2021-04-26" "2021-04-26" "2021-04-26" "2021-04-26" "2021-04-26" "2021-04-26"
    [35] "2021-04-26" "2021-04-26"
    >class(DateX)
    [1] "Date"
```

Now, my ggplot code using the newly created `DateX`:

```
>ggplot(df, aes(x=DateX, y=Dose, group = 1)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + facet_grid(Activity~User)
```

gives this graph which is great [image: image1].

Now I want to subset my data in `df` and plot only some of the `User` data

```
>ggplot(data = (subset(df,User %in% c("A" , "C", "G", "H"))), aes(x=DateX, y=Dose, group = 1)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + facet_grid(Activity~User)
```

But R gives this error

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (19): x
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Where am I going wrong? The subset is upsetting the code, but I can't figure it out.
Apologies if this layout is not ideal - still mastering this site!
thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using *two* data sources: `DateX` and `df`.

When you start, `DateX` is length 36, and `df` has 36 rows. Unfortunately, after you subset the data, `df` now has 19 rows while `DateX` is still length 36.

There are several ways to fix this, but if possible I recommend changing the using the external `DateX` to using `Date`, fixed in the frame.

```r
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, format='%d/%m/%Y')
ggplot(data = (subset(df,User %in% c("A" , "C", "G", "H"))), aes(x=Date, y=Dose, group = 1)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  facet_grid(Activity~User)
```

[image]

---

Data

```r
df <- structure(list(Date.Issued = c("28/04/2021 13:19", "28/04/2021 08:59", "28/04/2021 08:58", "28/04/2021 08:58", "28/04/2021 08:58", "28/04/2021 08:44", "28/04/2021 08:43", "28/04/2021 08:43", "28/04/2021 08:42", "28/04/2021 08:31", "28/04/2021 08:23", "28/04/2021 08:23", "28/04/2021 08:11", "27/04/2021 09:17", "27/04/2021 09:12", "27/04/2021 09:11", "27/04/2021 09:11", "27/04/2021 09:10", "27/04/2021 09:07", "27/04/2021 08:51", "27/04/2021 08:16", "27/04/2021 08:16", "27/04/2021 08:16", "26/04/2021 13:00", "26/04/2021 09:30", "26/04/2021 09:17", "26/04/2021 08:53", "26/04/2021 08:52", "26/04/2021 08:27", "26/04/2021 08:26", "26/04/2021 08:25", "26/04/2021 08:25", "26/04/2021 08:24", "26/04/2021 08:24", "26/04/2021 08:20", "26/04/2021 08:01"), Date = structure(c(18745, 18745, 18745, 18745, 18745, 18745, 18745, 18745, 18745, 18745, 18745, 18745, 18745, 18744, 18744, 18744, 18744, 18744, 18744, 18744, 18744, 18744, 18744, 18743, 18743, 18743, 18743, 18743, 18743, 18743, 18743, 18743, 18743, 18743, 18743, 18743), class = "Date"),     User = c("A", "G", "M", "L", "H", "G", "K", "R", "A", "P",     "C", "S", "H", "C", "G", "K", "A", "R", "G", "L", "S", "H",     "P", "A", "P", "G", "M", "C", "A", "R", "L", "K", "G", "C",     "S", "H"), Activity = c("Technologist PET", "Technologist PET",     "Technologist PET", "Technologist PET", "Technologist PET",     "Technologist NM", "Technologist NM", "Technologist NM",     "Technologist NM", "Technologist PET", "Technologist PET",     "Technologist PET", "Technologist PET", "Technologist PET",     "Technologist NM", "Technologist NM", "Technologist NM",     "Technologist NM", "Technologist PET", "Technologist PET",     "Technologist PET", "Technologist PET", "Technologist PET",     "Technologist PET", "Technologist PET", "Technologist PET",     "Technologist PET", "Technologist PET", "Technologist NM",     "Technologist NM", "Technologist NM", "Technologist NM",     "Technologist NM", "Technologist NM", "Technologist PET",     "Technologist PET"), Dose = c(3.3098681, 9.7787209, 6.4040399,     4.8086505, 0, 4.6328144, 12.4208622, 2.8641932, 8.4690704,     4.2168984, 28.1236839, 10.3116798, 13.7067385, 8.9209318,     3.84935, 2.3508735, 1.8516742, 3.922116, 15.1844616, 10.0322027,     8.2122355, 6.6248207, 3.8532472, 2.5060282, 9.5917282, 14.0576487,     4.3697691, 7.1182218, 2.1964765, 1.4743344, 3.4398077, 0.9920691,     1.4903276, 0, 8.9420223, 6.6264949)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Perfect thanks ! Makes sense. The subtle difference between using `df$Date` and `Datex` to keep it all inside the one data source is what I didn't understand.